# Indicate that the server is not launched

Tags: java, android, sockets, client, serversocket

I am developing an Android application in which the device connects to a socket with a Java server.
How I can do so that if the server is not launched the device to indicate that the server is not connected?

Answer (score 0):

An exception will be thrown if the socket cannot connect. So how about you catch that exception with `try...catch` and display a message or notification such as:

> The server is currently offline, please try again later.

This exception should be the `IOException` if the socket fails to connect.

1. `UnknownHostException` - if the IP address of the host could not be determined.
2. `IOException` - if an I/O error occurs when creating the socket.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html